# How to compute the frequency of occurrence of '+' and '++' in Java?

Tags: java, operators, frequency

I want to calculate the frequency of the occurrence of all the operators from an input text file. The file contains the operators `+` and `++`. How can I distinguish their respective frequency, as my program treats `++` as 2 distinct `+` operators rather than 1 `++`?

Here is my code (input7.txt is a test file):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input7.txt"))); //String to be counted 

    int frequencyArray[] = new int[string.length()]; 
    int frequencyArray2[] = new int[string.length()];

    char stringArray[] = string.toCharArray(); //Array of characters
    int i, j;

    //Count characters

    for (i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        frequencyArray[i] = 1;
        //frequencyArray2[i] = 1;

        for(j = i + 1; j < string.length(); j++) 
        {
            if(stringArray[i] == stringArray[j]) 
            {

                frequencyArray[i]++;    
                stringArray[j] = '0'; //To avoid revisiting a character

            }   
        }   
    }


    //Display results

    System.out.println("Characters and their corresponding frequencies");

    for (i = 0; i < frequencyArray.length; i++) {

        if (stringArray[i] != ' ' && stringArray[i] != '0') {

            System.out.println(stringArray[i] +"-" + frequencyArray[i]); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Share your code here

Comment: How many operators are there? What kind of grammar?

Comment: @TrushitShekhda I have added my code, thanks.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch arithmetic, increment, relational, logical, bitwise, and assignment operators.

Comment: @Milan Are you familiar with [Arthur C. Clarke's Quarantine](http://wargamerscott.tripod.com/swordandshield/id14.html)? It's ***very* short** (and also involves only six operators).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  String s = "sdfasd++ sdfadsf+asdf sdf++sadfasdf++sadfsdf+asdfasdf++";
            // create Set with all distinct characters 
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
              chars.add(s.charAt(i));
            }
// count distinct characters and put Results in HashMap
            Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
            for (Character c : chars) {
              int count = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == c)
                  count++;
              }
              counts.put(c, count);
            }
// Count double-Character-Operators like this
            int countPlusPlus = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
              if (s.substring(i, i + 2).equals("++"))
                countPlusPlus++;
            }
        // Calculate totals like this
            int singleplusTotal = counts.get('+');
            System.out.println("Single Plus total" + singleplusTotal);
            System.out.println("Double Plus total" + countPlusPlus);
            System.out.println("Only single Plus" + (singleplusTotal - countPlusPlus * 2));
```

Comment: This is not an efficient way to do this.